# Cannot adapt image to mockup

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mockup

I’ve purchased a mockup “[Surface Studio, Presentation Kit](https://creativemarket.com/ruslan_latypov/1725327-Presentation-Kit-Surface-Studio)” and I’m trying to replace the computer window with my own image. I actually achieved this, but I have a little problem: I’m working on the 6K resolution and my image doesn’t cover all the screen of the computer, infact as you can see from the red square (which I added) to header and footer of the screen, there is a blank background. This is an image which explain the issue:

[image]

Is there a way to fix that without stretching the image? Could you suggest me something?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using Content Aware scaling in Photoshop.

My screen isn't the same aspect ratio either, but with a little bit of Content Aware scaling, and manually fixing a few parts that got messed up, I was able to get a reasonable result.  Note that Content Aware scaling is not perfect, and success will depend on the image.

Example showing before and after.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have 4 options:

- edit the image, currently it has a different proportion than the space you're trying to fill
- add black bars to top+bottom
- stretch the image to fit, deforming it
- scale the image proportionally until it fits the space, but it will crop the image

Alternatively, you could edit the TV to fit your image.